# Time functions in C?

Tags: c

I have to find the date 4,000,000 seconds from now. I can get the correct answer if I add 4,000,000 to `secondsSince1970`, but I was wondering why it doesn't work if I add 4,000,000 to `now.tm_sec`?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    long secondsSince1970 = time(NULL) + 4000000;

    struct tm now;

    localtime_r(&secondsSince1970, &now);

    printf("The date from 4,000,000 seconds from now is %i-%i-%i\n", now.tm_mon + 1, now.tm_wday, now.tm_year + 1900);
}
```

Output:
The date is 10-1-2012

---

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    long secondsSince1970 = time(NULL);

    struct tm now;

    localtime_r(&secondsSince1970, &now);
    now.tm_sec += 4000000;

    printf("The date from 4,000,000 seconds from now is %i-%i-%i\n", now.tm_mon + 1, now.tm_wday, now.tm_year + 1900);
}
```

Output: The date is 8-4-2012

Comment: Ah okay, it seemed to be asking the same thing though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `struct tm` is just a bunch of variables that get filled in by `localtime_r`. After the call to `localtime_r`, assigning to one of these variables will not magically make the other ones change *their* values.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a value to `tm_sec` is simply changing the integer member of `now`.  The easiest way to do what you are trying to do is to pass the `struct tm` into [`mktime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/mktime.html) to convert it back into a `time_t`.  Then call `localtime_r` on the resulting value.

```
void
add_seconds(struct tm* broken, int num_seconds) {
   time_t then;
   broken->tm_sec += num_seconds;
   then = mktime(broken);
   localtime_r(&then, broken);
}

int
main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    time_t secondsSince1970 = time(NULL);
    struct tm now;
    localtime_r(&secondsSince1970, &now);
    add_seconds(&now, 4000000);
    printf("The date at 4,000,000 seconds from now is %i-%i-%i\n",
           now.tm_mon + 1, now.tm_mday, now.tm_year + 1900);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Sorry if this question is stupid. I thought that the way to access and assign the member's of a struct variable is to state the struct variable name, followed by a dot, the member's name and then assign it a value with an =?

Comment: @stumped: In this code sample, you have pointers to the struct rather than the struct itself. So in principle you would write `(*broken).tm_sec = ...` to assign a member. However, the `(*abc).def` construction is so common that it has a shorter abbreviation baked into the language, namely `abc->def`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However I don't understand how I declared a pointer to the struct when I didn't use the * sign in front of the `now`?

Comment: You can create a pointer to `now` by using the "address of" operator - `&now` is a pointer to a `struct tm`.

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect to do this:

```
now.tm_sec += 4000000;
```

You tm_sec needs to be between 0 and 59 (60 for leap second).

You would need to do something like:

```
now.tm_sec += 4000000;
now.tm_min += now.tm_sec / 60; now.tm_sec %= 60;
now.tm_hour += now.tm_min / 60; now.tm_min %= 60;
etc.
```

Comment: But once you get to months and years, it is nowhere as simple as that, because months and years have different lengths, and a priori you could be jumping over any number of them. The only sane solution is to convert back to unix time, _then_ do arithmetic and finally convert to ymdhms once again.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Hence my "etc." :)